# Understanding the implications of singular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

### Context

An over-determined system of equations can not be generally solved by elimination operated on $Ax = b$.

Instead, it normally involves solving $$(A^t A) x = A^t b$$

which is [obtained in the OLS method.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares), this is, assuming we choose the sum of squared errors as the cost function.

Simplifying the $A$s product inverse to just $B$ then we could to LU decomposition  $ B =  LU $ and **if**
$U$ has some zeroes in the diagonal then:

- some columns are linearly dependent
- it means $r<n$,
- and $Det(B)=0$,
- and $B^{-1}$ does not exist.

But does this means we can't find a solution ? Could you hint me why it is so conceptually, and how it relates to the obvious properties listed above ?

Comment: an "over-determined" system of equations should imply $A$ is not square, and you cannot talk about $\det(A)$ or a matrix inverse for non-square $A$.  You also never defined $r$.

Comment: Good observation, but if you read the post I am using $AAt$ which is square @user8675309, I've replaced the name for $B$ for clarity.

Comment: It is quite possible to solve an overdetermined system $Ax = b$ directly by elimination, although there may be complications in doing so numerically because of difficulty in deciding whether a matrix element is or is not $0$.

Comment: I think you mean $A^t A x = A^t b$ or $x = (A^t A)^{-1} A^t b$, not $(A^t A)^{-1} x = A^t b$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael from what I read, a rectangular matrix with m > n, assuming that the column vectors are linearly independent then the rank would be $r = n  <  m$, the reduced form would have $m - r$ zero rows, and the system has 0 or infinite solutions, but if you find some of these infinite solutions none would be as good as the one found by minimizing Sum of Squared Errors

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes, thank you, is there any chance I could pay you for a lesson in linear algebra, I'm a programmer and struggling with some stuff.